Selecting the Scherrer constant
I study materials chemistry and need to work some problems with the Scherrer equation. However, the problems never mention what the Scherrer constant is, and it seems like it is different in every problem; so how should I select it? What determines it?

Two main causes originate the broadening of a diffraction line:

size and strain broadening related to intrinsic structural properties of the sample;
instrumental contribution.

To obtain information on the structural properties of the sample, the instrumental contribution must be subtracted when diffraction line broadening is performed. By blindly applying the Scherrer equation by setting K=n (where n can vary from 0.62 to 2.08) the result changes depending on the arbitrary value of K selected. For proper analysis, you should also analyze a standard LaB6, where the contributions to strain and size broadening are (hopefully) negligible (you should collect the standard LaB6 and the sample using the same experimental conditions). Then, you select a peak in the LaB6 diffraction pattern that is at approximately the same angle as the diffraction peak selected for your material. You then measure the full width at half maximum (FWHM) in the LaB6 peak and subtract this value from the FWHM of your sample's peak. The number obtained represents the contribution to the expansion of the dimensions (or deformation).
The best thing would be to apply this method by first using a nanometric sample with homogeneous particles of known size (or rather, diffracting domains) to check whether constant corrections are necessary.
